# Getting popular posts most reacted or liked in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table where i store a posts reaction and like status, which can be like = 1 and unlike = 0, i am trying to count the total likes and echo the posts with more than 20 likes over a period of time. I also want to count based on the reaction_id. how do i go about this. Here is the table

[image]

Comment: Where are the likes? Where are the dislikes? Based on the reaction_id? What does "based on" mean?

Comment: the likes are based on the type row, a 0 means unlike while a 1 means like. The reaction_id is linked to a different table that has the name of the reaction with the id.